# Override interactive function with advice

Tags: emacs, defadvice

How can I override interactive input with `defadvice` in elisp?

For example, I am trying to stop `ansi-term` from prompting for input with the following:

```
(defadvice ansi-term (around kill-interactive activate)
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash"))
    (ad-set-arg 0 explicit-shell-file-name)
    (deactivate-input-method)
    ad-do-it))
```

But, it still prompts even though `explicit-shell-file-name` is set correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function still has its original `interactive` declaration, so if you call it interactively, it will use it to obtain argument values.

You can replace the `interactive` form by including it in your advice. e.g.:

```el
(defadvice ansi-term (around kill-interactive activate)
  (interactive (list "/bin/bash" nil))
  ad-do-it)
```

And indeed that's exactly where you *should* be setting the argument value if using advice like this, otherwise you're clobbering the `PROGRAM` value for *non-interactive* uses of ansi-term as well, which is clearly not what you want here!

Personally I wouldn't do any of that, however. I'd define a new wrapper command, and invoke that instead:

```el
(defun bash ()
  "Run bash inside `ansi-term'."
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/bin/bash"))
```

If you have any keybindings for `ansi-term` you could then remap them like so:

```el
(global-set-key [remap ansi-term] 'bash)
```